# How to draw polyline on google map in flutter

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter, google-polyline

I'm trying to draw polyline between two location with using flutter google map library.

```dart
// here the  Map Body

          body:Container(
        child: GoogleMap(
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          mapType: MapType.hybrid,
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
            mapController=controller;
          }, 
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
           target: center,
           zoom: 11.0 
         ),
         markers:  markers,
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've found a solution to this but just in case someone else find themselves here...

Here's how you'd do that.

```dart
List<Polyline> _polyLine = [];

_polyLine.add(Polyline(
        polylineId: PolylineId("route1"),
        color: Colors.blue,
        patterns: [
          PatternItem.dash(20.0),
          PatternItem.gap(10)
        ],
        width: 3,
        points: [
          LOCATION_A,
          LOCATION_B,
        ],
      ));
.
.
.
.

GoogleMap(
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          mapType: MapType.hybrid,
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
            mapController=controller;
          }, 
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
           target: center,
           zoom: 11.0 
         ),
         markers:  markers,
         polylines: _polyLine.toSet(),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use inside Google() widget `polygons` and try like this

```
        GoogleMap(
                    markers: markersAr,
                    myLocationEnabled: true,
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(6.843369, 79.874814),

                      zoom: 12.99,
                    ),
                    polygons: Set<Polygon>.of(<Polygon>[
                      Polygon(
                          polygonId: PolygonId('area'),
                          points: getPoints(),
                          geodesic: true,
                          strokeColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.6),
                          strokeWidth: 5,
                          fillColor: Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(0.1),
                          visible: true),


                    ]),)
```

put your coordinate into

> getPoint()

```
getPoints() {
    return [
      LatLng(6.862472, 79.859482),
      LatLng(6.862258, 79.862325),
      LatLng(6.863121, 79.863644),
      LatLng(6.864538, 79.865039),
      LatLng(6.865124, 79.864546),
      LatLng(6.866451, 79.864667),
      LatLng(6.867303, 79.86544),
      LatLng(6.867899, 79.865826),
      LatLng(6.867867, 79.866727),
      LatLng(6.864884, 79.870333),
      LatLng(6.861859, 79.873112),
      LatLng(6.861593, 79.87499),
      LatLng(6.860837, 79.876427),

    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using goole_maps_flutter plugin, on ver.0.5.6, support for polylines have been added to GoogleMaps. 
https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter#056

you can add it similar to how you add markers:

```
body:Container(
    child: GoogleMap(
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      mapType: MapType.hybrid,
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
        mapController=controller;
      }, 
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
       target: center,
       zoom: 11.0 
     ),
     markers:  markers,
     polylines: polylines, // Set<Polyline>
    ),
  ),
```

check out the following example:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_polyline.dart